# what can we do when we're struggling with rhythmic notation?

Tags: rhythm, sight-reading

How can a music teacher help his pupils who have no rhythm feeling at all, who are not able to count or speak in a rhythmical way? How can we improve rhythm reading? Is there a helping method for people  having problems with rhythmic notation and rhythm feeling?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89411/discussion-on-question-by-albrecht-hugli-what-can-we-do-when-were-struggling-wi).

Answer (score 2):

Count. Count out loud. Write down the words used for counting on the score lined up with the notes and rests in question. Practice counting out loud every practice. Practice counting so much that the count becomes part of the music.

Obviously that's less helpful for any musician playing a breath operated instrument. For them, I suppose trying to count silently in one's mind while perhaps tapping the foot might be the best one can do.

Comment: Count sounds good! But what about children and even adults that are not able to count in an simple  rhythmic measure of quarters?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli I have yet to encounter such a person, although I'm sure they exist. I really don't know. If someone can't count "one two three four" with at least somewhat even time divisions between each number, then I might have to refer them to another teacher.

Comment: as I commented above one was my godson. I had thousands of children at school (I've been singing teacher at secondary schools for about 40 years, and as already mentioned here somewhere I had pupils in guitar groups - they were not mentally handicapped! and they showed similar disabilities that other music schools told the parents it were senseless to give them a musical education ... as they were the ones who needed it most.